# Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

Um número é dito ser *capicua* quando lido da esquerda para a direita é o mesmo que quando lido da direita para a esquerda. Por exemplo: o número 320023 é *capicua*, enquanto o número 1872681 não é. Então, construa uma função em C para verificar se um número inteiro lido é capicua. A função deve retornar 1 se o número for capicua e 0 caso contrário. Escreva também um algoritmo que lê ”n” números e escreve junto a cada um deles a mensagem “SIM” se o número é “capicua” e “NÃO” no caso contrário. Não utilizar os comandos “se” ou “caso”.

No meu algoritmo ocorre o erro mencionado no título.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define color "color 1F"

int capicua(int n);
int propriedade(int n);
void ler_capicua();

int main(int agrc, char *argv[]){

int n;
system(color);
setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

printf("Digite um número: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
capicua(n);
ler_capicua();
propriedade(n);
}

int capicua(int n){

  int x=n, r=0;

while(x!=0){
    r=r*10;
    r=r+x%10;
    x=x/10;
}

if(n==r){
    printf("%d é um número \"capicua\"",n);
}

else{
    printf("%d não é um número \"capicua\"",n);
}

  sleep(3);
  system("cls");
}

int propriedade(int n){

  int contrario=0, aux=n, x, i;

printf("Digite um número para saber se possui essa propriedade: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Quantos algarismos esse número possui? ");
scanf("%d",&x);

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    contrario=contrario*10;
    contrario=contrario+aux%10;
    aux=aux/10;
    if(aux==0) break;
}

if(n==contrario) return 1;
else return 0;

  sleep(3);
  system("cls");
}

void ler_capicua(){
  int n, i;

printf("\nInsira quantidade de números que queria calcular: ");
scanf("%d",&i);

while(i>0){
    printf("\nInsira o número: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(capicua(n) == 1) printf("SIM");
    else print("NÃO");
    i--;
}   
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, sugiro que você use identação.

Answer (score 0):

Ao executar o seu código o erro que apareceu foi

> /tmp/ccXQBEq3.o: na função `ler_capicua':
>
> arquivo.c:(.text+0x25c): referência indefinida para `print'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Não cheguei a testar e validar completamente o seu código, mas algumas boas práticas posso lhe recomendar:

1. Ler toda mensagem de erro, assim você pode ter uma ideia melhor do que está acontecendo. No seu caso, pelo menos com base no que o compilador informou aqui, ficou claro que existe uma chamada a uma função indefinida chamada `print` (isso aparece bem no final do seu código). Troque para `printf` que funciona.
2. Usar identação. É muito mais fácil para enxergar as instruções que fazem parte de suas funções, estruturas de condição, seleção etc.

**EDIÇÃO**: Fiz uma alteração pequena no código, mas que você já pode se acostumar, que foi remover o `else` após um `return`. Ele é desnecessário.

Veja o código corrigido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int capicua(int n);
int propriedade(int n);
void ler_capicua();

int main(int agrc, char *argv[]) {
    int n;
    printf("Digite um número: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    capicua(n);
    ler_capicua();
    propriedade(n);
}

int capicua(int n) {
    int x = n, r = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        r=r*10;
        r=r+x%10;
        x=x/10;
    }
    if (n == r)
        printf("%d é um número \"capicua\"",n);
    else
        printf("%d não é um número \"capicua\"",n);
}

int propriedade(int n) {
    int contrario = 0, aux = n, x, i;
    printf("Digite um número para saber se possui essa propriedade: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Quantos algarismos esse número possui? ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        contrario = contrario * 10;
        contrario = contrario + aux % 10;
        aux = aux/10;
        if (aux == 0) break;
    }

    if (n == contrario) return 1;
    return 0;
}

void ler_capicua() {
    int n, i;
    printf("\nInsira quantidade de números que queria calcular: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    while (i > 0) {
        printf("\nInsira o número: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (capicua(n) == 1) printf("SIM");
        else printf("NÃO");
        i--;
    }   
}
```